# How destruction function is getting called?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Monster {

  public: 
  Monster() {cout << "with out argument. \n";}
  Monster(int sz) { cout << "Monster created.\n"; }
  ~Monster() { cout << "Monster destroyed.\n"; }

  int GetSize() { return itsSize; }
  void SetSize(int str) { itsSize = str; }

private:
  int itsSize;
};

int main()
{
  Monster *m;
  m =new Monster[3];
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     m[i] = i; // constructor with argument is getting called for each elements after which why destructor is getting called for each element.          
  delete []m;
  return 0;
}

Output:
with out argument. 
with out argument. 
with out argument. 
Monster created. // Monster constructor with argument is getting called.
Monster destroyed. // 1. Why this destructor is getting called after each call of constructor.
Monster created.
Monster destroyed. //2.
Monster created.
Monster destroyed. //3.
Monster destroyed.
Monster destroyed.
Monster destroyed.
```

When i am initializing Array of Monster object with value, parameterized constructor is getting called, immediately after which why destructor is getting called?

Comment: You should annotate the copy and move constructors (and assignments) as well to get a clearer picture. They will give you a better idea of temporaries etc. floating around in the code.

Comment: `m[i] = i;` you're storing integers into that pointer array, is that really what you wanted?

Comment: Here is a sample of the "noisy" `Monster`... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8456e3bec85d185

Comment: There's days you're better off using `std::vector` than doing this sort of thing using pointers...

Comment: @Niall Perhaps if that was `(*m[i]) = i`.

Comment: @Niall oh wait my bad, I misread that. Nevermind everything I said.

Comment: @Niall I just want to know the reason that the scope of m[i] is till end of the program, then why after calling constructor, destructor is immediately getting called in alternative way?  And also, i created 3 object only but why six times constructor is getting called?

Comment: The assignment in the loop... you create a temporary `Monster` in each iteration and move assign it to `m[i]`, the temporary is then destroyed. You create 3 object in the `new Monster[3]` and three more (1 for each loop) - hence you see 6 being destroyed. The posted answer covers this as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
m =new Monster[3];
```

Here three objects are created, default constructor was called for each of them. That's why you see messages `with out argument.`

```
m[i] = i;
```

First, temporary Monster is created on right-hand-side by using `Monster(int)` constructor. That's why you see message `Monster created.` Next, assignment operator is called. Next, your temporary Monster is deleted. That's why you see  `Monster destroyed.`.

```
delete []m;
```

Three Monsters from array are destroyed.

---

To better understand such situations, I suggest that you add address of `this` to all your messages.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. ;) [live demo](http://ideone.com/jeKMZZ) The temporary object that is constructed is move-assigned into your array, but the temporary itself is still being destroyed. Move-assignment doesn't move the object itself, but just its ownership of resources.